# How can I draw a chart in the economist style with pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to draw a chart with "The Economist" style.
With tikz, I draw this chart clumsily, so I would like to know is that possible to draw this chart elegantly with pgfplots.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ybar]
        \draw[red,thin] (0,0) -- (3.6,0) node [right,color=black,font=\footnotesize] {0};
        \draw[white,thin] (0,0.5) -- (3.6,0.5) node [right,color=black,font=\footnotesize] {10};
        \draw[white,thin] (0,1) -- (3.6,1) node [right,color=black,font=\footnotesize] {20};
        \draw[white,thin] (0,1.5) -- (3.6,1.5) node [right,color=black,font=\footnotesize] {30};
        \draw[white,thin] (0,2) -- (3.6,2) node [right,color=black,font=\footnotesize] {40};
        \draw[white,thin] (0,2.5) -- (3.6,2.5) node [right,color=black,font=\footnotesize] {50};
        \draw[white,thin] (0,3) -- (3.6,3) node [right,color=black,font=\footnotesize] {60};
        \draw[color=blue,fill=blue!40!black,bar width=8pt] 
            plot coordinates {(1.2,0.85)} node [above,color=black,font=\tiny] {WWI};
        \draw[color=blue,fill=blue!60,bar width=8pt] 
            plot coordinates {(2.4,2.5)} node [above,color=black,font=\tiny] {Spanish Flu};
        \draw[color=red,fill=red] (-0.3,4) rectangle (-0.5,4.5);
        \node[below right] at (-0.3,4.5) {
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                \footnotesize\textbf{Mortality}\\
                \tiny{million}\\                    
            \end{tabular}
            };
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \fill[blue!90!black!25] (-0.5,4.5) rectangle (4.5,-0.4);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

There are some questions:

1. How to hide y axis but remain the ytick and y major grid?
2. Can I set the separation space between ticks?
3. How to add a red rectangle in the title and move it to the upper left corner?

Thank you for your kindly help!

Comment: Could you edit your code to turn it into a compilable document?

Answer (score 28):

1. To only hide the y axis line but keep the ticks and the grid, you can use `y axis line style={opacity=0}` to make the line transparent (`draw=none` doesn't seem to work here).
2. To specify the interval between the ticks, it is usually easiest to set them using something like `ytick={0,10,...,100}`.
3. The rectangle can be added using `extra description/.code={...}`. The standard coordinate system for TikZ commands in this context is the `axis description cs`, where `(0,0)` is the lower left corner of the plot area, and `(1,1)` is the upper right. You can use values `<0` and `>1`. In this case, I would also typeset the title as an `extra description`, because it's easier to get the positioning right. To make the rectangle appear snug in the corner, you should set `tight background rectangle` for the background, otherwise TikZ will add some padding.

Here's an example where I defined a new `economist` style for an axis environment. The style takes an optional argument to define the title.

As maetra points out, the style seems to have changed at some point in 2012. I have included a second style, `economist new` that uses a white background and a frame around the labels.

[image: PGFplots chart in The Economist Style]

[image: PGFPlots chart in new The Economist Style]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{213,228,235}
\definecolor{plotcolor1}{RGB}{1,77,100}
\definecolor{plotcolor2}{RGB}{1,162,217}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{economist}{%
    fill=plotcolor1,draw=plotcolor1,text=black\\%
    fill=plotcolor2,draw=plotcolor2,text=black\\%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    economist/.style={
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        enlarge x limits=1.5,
        nodes near coords,
        every axis plot post/.append style={
            point meta=explicit symbolic
        },
        /tikz/background rectangle/.style={
            fill=backgroundcolor
        },
        tight background,
        show background rectangle,
        cycle list name=economist,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        x axis line style={black},
        xtick=\empty,
        axis y line=right,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        ytick={0,10,...,100},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        grid=major,
        grid style=white,
        extra description/.code={
            \fill [red] (-0.05,1.15) rectangle +(-1em,6ex);
            \node [anchor=base west, inner sep=0pt] at (0,1.15) {\large\textbf{#1}};
            \node [anchor=base west, inner sep=0pt] at (0,1.075) {\small Million};
        },
    },
    economist/.default={},
    economist new/.style={
        economist=#1,
        /tikz/background rectangle/.style={
            fill=white
        },
        grid style=gray!50,
        every node near coord/.append style={
            draw=cyan!50!blue,
            fill=white,
            inner sep=2pt,
            outer sep=3pt
        }
    },
    economist new/.default={},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[economist new=Mortality, ymax=60]
\addplot coordinates {(1,18) [WW1]};
\addplot coordinates {(2,50) [Spanish Flu]};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly Jake, my text live version in ubuntu 11.10 was an old one (2009). Now installed Tex Live 2011 and it works!

Comment: Looks great. Is there a way to draw the plots behind the grind?

Comment: @schmendrich: Thanks! You can just set `axis on top` to draw the grid lines on top of the plot.

Comment: @Jake, it seems as if the Economist has a different style now, as least on its website: The background is white while the lines are grey. Also if the line crosses the coordinate information like WW1, there is a [box around the label](http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2012/12/daily-chart-19).

Comment: @maetra: Ah yes, indeed! I've edited my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: If somebody wants to use the same commercial font as The Economist, one has to buy [ITC Officina Display](http://spiekermann.com/en/itc-officina-display/). [Trebuchet](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ascender/trebuchet/) might be an alternative for Windows Users, since it comes with Windows.

Comment: @Jake, they seem to use the grey background for [forecasts](http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2013/01/daily-chart-3) only. Maybe sometime you could add chart like that to your answer?