# How to draw bar chart using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I have drawn the above figure using powerpoint, how can I plot something similar using tikz?

I want the 3 different sections in every bar which should ve 3 different colors

---------edit after 1st answer------

I am using the code from 1st answer but all my bars are overlapping
why?

```
    \documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
Label   First   Second  Third
10      0.1     0.3     0.3
20      0.2     0.3     0.3
30      0.3     0.4     0.5
40      0.3     0.5     0.8
160     0.5     0.9     1.5
}\datatable

\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
    xmin=0,         % Start x axis at 0
    ytick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Label}  % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
]
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=First, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};    % Plot the "First" column against the data index
\addplot [fill=green!70!blue]table [x=Second, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=red!80!yellow] table [x=Third, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
-------edit------

I updated my pgfplots package and now everything is working as expected!

Comment: You should be able to work out something using this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22429/how-can-i-draw-a-chart-in-the-economist-style-with-pgfplots?rq=1. Basically, look at `pgfplots` to make this type of graphs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use PGFPlots for this. It has an `xbar stacked` style that uses stacked horizontal bars. Here's an example based on your image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
Label   First   Second  Third
10      0.1     0.3     0.3
20      0.2     0.3     0.3
30      0.3     0.4     0.5
40      0.3     0.5     0.8
160     0.5     0.9     1.5
}\datatable

\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
    xmin=0,         % Start x axis at 0
    ytick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Label}  % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
]
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=First, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};    % Plot the "First" column against the data index
\addplot [fill=green!70!blue]table [x=Second, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=red!80!yellow] table [x=Third, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why are all bars overlapping when I use the same code?

Comment: Are you using exactly the same code? Then they shouldn't be overlapping. Are you sure that you have the `y expr=\coordindex` keys in your code?

Comment: yes...i ve just changed the value inside the table...but nothing else

Comment: @user494461: Please edit your question to include the complete code (including the changed values)

Comment: i have edited my orignal question

Comment: @user494461: I can't reproduce this. What version of PGFPlots are you using (check in your `.log` file)?

Comment: Package: pgfplots 2010/07/14 Version 1.4.1 (git show 1.4.1-1-g64c9e95 )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7665/discussion-between-jake-and-user494461)