# How to specify the starting point of a horizontal bar in latex?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, bar-chart

How to specify the starting point of a horizontal bar in latex ? For example, I want to plot a horizontal bar between `(2, 5)` and `(10, 5)`, which is a horizontal bar with a length of `8` and starting at `2`. I have tried both `bchart` package and `pgfplots` package, but I have no means to work it around. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, I don't understand what your units are. Second: have you tried TikZ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried the Tikz. The units could be em, cm, or any other things. Sorry that I doesn't describe it clearly and make you confusing. Do you suggest me to try Tikz?

Comment: If you have used pgfplots, you have already used tikz.  Tikz is the engine which runs pgfplots.

Comment: As you suggested, I searched "horizontal bar with tikz" in google and find the a similar result in [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99832/how-to-draw-bar-chart-using-tikz). I think that will be enough to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply draw it by yourself. `pgfplots` is used to draw the axis while it is possible to draw it using `tikz` too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ymin=0,ymax=10,
        ytick={1,2,...,10},
        yticklabels={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}
        ]
      \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm]10,1) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm]50,1)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{40};
      \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm]2,2) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm]10,2)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{8};
      \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm]50,3) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm]75,3)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{25};
      \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm]10,4) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm]80,4)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{70};
      \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm]50,5) rectangle
              ([yshift=2.5mm]90,5)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{40};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]