# How to place a bar one on the other in bar charts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I know how to draw for single data...

but How to draw the bars one on the other where the data's grouped

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={2006,2007,2008},
            xtick=data
          ]
            \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
                (2006,   42)
                (2007,  50)
                (2008,   0)
             };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My data is like this, Number of students in a year batch wise,

```
$$\begin{matrix}{cccc}
year  &  batch 1&   batch 2 &    batch 3\\

2006  &   42  &      87   &       8\\

2007   & 50        & 90        & \\

2008    &      &     78  &        90 
\end{matrix}$$
```

Now I want the data on the respective bars. Like in the following diagram.. It no need to be a 3D diagram.

How to do that??

[image]

Comment: You're after a stacked bar chart, *i.e.* `ybar stacked`. See for example [How to draw bar chart using tikz?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99834)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. May yo tell me how to place the yvalues on the bars? Kindly see this question also. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317775/how-to-get-the-spaces-properly-on-the-x-axis-how-to-place-the-y-values-on-the-c