# pgfplot/tikz stacked bar chart, with compat=1.9 or later

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

Inspired by this question, [pgfplot/tikz stacked bar chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321000/pgfplot-tikz-stacked-bar-chart), I've been trying to create a stacked bar chart with numbers at the end of the stacked bars. However, the location of `nodes near coords` was changed in pgfplot v1.9 to be over the centre of the bar segment. I've tried several things including setting `nodes near coords style={text depth=2cm}` but this obviously doesn't move with the data values. I've also tried making a 'topper' series, but this isn't the greatest solution IMO, and messes with `reverse legend=true` (though, this could be fixed with a more manually specified legend).

**Would work pre 1.9:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} % set to 1.8 to get old behaviour

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotstableread{
Label series1 series2 series3
A 21.87797  5.566584 24.85545
B 20.93009  7.937881 24.33203
C 20.41148 21.126529 27.56199
D 26.83072 23.823827 28.94545
    }\testdata

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        xtick=data,
        legend style={cells={anchor=west}, legend pos=north west},
        reverse legend=true,
        xticklabels from table={\testdata}{Label},
        xticklabel style={text width=2cm,align=center},
    ]
    \addplot [fill=green!80] table [y=series1, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
    \addlegendentry{series1}
    \addplot [fill=blue!60] table [y=series2, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
    \addlegendentry{series2}
    \addplot [fill=red!60,nodes near coords,point meta=y] table [y=series3, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
    \addlegendentry{series3}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: stacked bar chart with total over last segment]

**'topper' solution:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} % set to 1.8 to get old behaviour

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotstableread{
Label series1 series2 series3 topper
A 21.87797  5.566584 24.85545 0.001
B 20.93009  7.937881 24.33203 0.001
C 20.41148 21.126529 27.56199 0.001
D 26.83072 23.823827 28.94545 0.001
    }\testdata

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        xtick=data,
        legend style={cells={anchor=west}, legend pos=north west},
        reverse legend=true, % set to false to get correct display, but I'd like to have this true
        xticklabels from table={\testdata}{Label},
        xticklabel style={text width=2cm,align=center},
    ]
    \addplot [fill=green!80] table [y=series1, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
    \addlegendentry{series1}
    \addplot [fill=blue!60] table [y=series2, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
    \addlegendentry{series2}
    \addplot [fill=red!60] table [y=series3, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
    \addlegendentry{series3}
    \addplot [nodes near coords,point meta=y,nodes near coords style={anchor=south}] table [y=topper, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: stacked bar chart with total above last segment, using topper solution]

Comment: Did my answer answer your question or was it at least helpful? If yes, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to set the `compat/bar nodes` level back to `1.8`. By doing that you can use all new features set by `compat` level except for the explicitly single set `compat/...` features.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.9,
        compat/bar nodes=1.8,
    }
    \pgfplotstableread{
        Label series1 series2 series3
        A 21.87797  5.566584 24.85545
        B 20.93009  7.937881 24.33203
        C 20.41148 21.126529 27.56199
        D 26.83072 23.823827 28.94545
    }\testdata
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        xtick=data,
        legend style={
            cells={anchor=west},
            legend pos=north west,
        },
        reverse legend=true,
        xticklabels from table={\testdata}{Label},
        xticklabel style={text width=2cm,align=center},
    ]
        \addplot [fill=green!80]
            table [y=series1, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex]
                {\testdata};
                    \addlegendentry{series1}
        \addplot [fill=blue!60]
            table [y=series2, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex]
                {\testdata};
                    \addlegendentry{series2}
        \addplot [fill=red!60,nodes near coords,point meta=y]
            table [y=series3, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex]
                {\testdata};
                    \addlegendentry{series3}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 1):

The "topper" solution can be refined a little, to remove the requirement that you must have a table column with the near-zero data by setting the `y expr` key to a small constant instead. The legend is still broken, though.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{biblatex} % so can use same script/recipie as actual documents
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotstableread{
Label series1 series2 series3
A 21.87797  5.566584 24.85545
B 20.93009  7.937881 24.33203
C 20.41148 21.126529 27.56199
D 26.83072 23.823827 28.94545
    }\testdata

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        xtick=data,
        legend style={cells={anchor=west}, legend pos=north west},
        reverse legend=true, % set to false to get correct display, but I'd like to have this true
        xticklabels from table={\testdata}{Label},
        xticklabel style={text width=2cm,align=center},
    ]
    \addplot [fill=green!80] table [y=series1, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
    \addlegendentry{series1}
    \addplot [fill=blue!60] table [y=series2, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
    \addlegendentry{series2}
    \addplot [fill=red!60] table [y=series3, meta=Label, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
    \addlegendentry{series3}
    \addplot [
        ybar, % this makes it show the total for some reason
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={%
            anchor=south,%
        },
    ] table [ y expr=0.00001, x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting plot, looks correct with labels above stacked bars, except the legend which shows the wrong colours]